# TableView fixed first column

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Is it possible to set the first column in my TableView to be always visible whenever the user scrolls to the right?

Comment: provide 2 table views. one for the first column and the other for the rest

Answer (score 1):

That feature is currently not supported by TableView in JavaFX. You are welcome to raise a JIRA issue here (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net) in order to ask for that feature.

Nevertheless, you could have a look at a third party project name [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) where you have a control named [SpreadsheetView](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#spreadsheetview) which has this actual feature you want.

Comment: Thanks I've changed it